# ChipNavigationBar how to initialize the java code

Tags: java, xml

Good day, can anyone help me to run or initialize the java code of ChipNavigationBar? can anybody help me with the right java code? the XML. file is working fine and menu directories, all I need to do is to implement click on my navigation bar.

This is the error message from logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar cannot be cast to 
com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView 
`at dealmagnet.com.home.Owner.onCreate(Owner.java:34)`
```

Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72'
```

Java Code

```
//Line 34 from logcat error mssg is the first line here
    BottomNavigationView navigationBar = findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
    navigationBar.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_menu);
    navigationBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            try {

            switch ( menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home_menu:
                    return true;
                case  R.id.search_menu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case  R.id.notification_menu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case  R.id.account_menu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case  R.id.settings_menu:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Setting.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
            }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can anybody please help me with my question? It would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Cast unconvertable classes that's what Logcat is telling you.

```
BottomNavigationView navigationBar = findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
```

If you are using [this](https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar) library then you need to use as follows -

**in xml file**

```
<com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    ........
 />
```

**in your java code**

```
ChipNavigationBar navigationBar = findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
//rest of your code
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: Done Sir Nik :), Thank you